# Get last insertion from a series

Tags: mongodb

I'm building a series of data for each user using my application.

The document format is following

```
{ "userId": String, "timestamp": DateTime, "data": Data }
```

I'm looking for a simple query to get last inserted data (with "timestamp") for a list of users (with "userId").

See my current implementation.

```
userIds.forEach(function(id){
  db.data.find({"userId":id}).sort({"timestamp":-1}).limit(1);
});
```

Comment: As a result of this query do you want to get 1 document, or a set of documents (for each `userId` the oldest `data`)?

Comment: I need one document per ```userId```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`aggregation-framework`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to accomplish it. Aggregation pipeline with one [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage and [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator on `timestamp` field

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate( 
  { $group: { _id: "$userId", "last": { $max: "$timestamp" } } } 
);
```

for collection of documents

```
{ "userId" : "1", "timestamp" : 1470385420806, "data" : "123" }
{ "userId" : "1", "timestamp" : 1470386440616, "data" : "456" }
{ "userId" : "2", "timestamp" : 1470385598845, "data" : "222" }
{ "userId" : "2", "timestamp" : 1470385602249, "data" : "333" }
```

will give you the result

```
{ "_id" : "1", "last" : 1470386440616 }
{ "_id" : "2", "last" : 1470385602249 }
```

that seems to be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can state multiple users in query, sort them by timestamp and return just one. Just like this:

`db.users.find({userId: {$in:[your_list_ids]}}, {fields_you_need}).sort({timestamp: -1}).limit(1)`

So, this request finds all users in group (everyone, whose userId is in array), then sorts them descendingly by "timestamp" field and limits your output with 1 record.

Remember! To keep sortings fast, you have to apply index to sorted field.

Comment: If I request 4 ids, the result should have 4 results.